# GoogleCredential deprecation

Tags: google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

We want to implement Google OAUTH to play nicely with our web-app based credentials. Flow starts on UI side, which shows user consent screen, and then we obtain a code. That code is then sent to our java based back-end to get refresh token.

At the moment we use this approach:

```java
 private Analytics getAnalytics(String refreshToken) throws Exception {

        NetHttpTransport httpTransport =
                GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        JsonFactory jsonFactory =
                JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        return new Analytics.Builder(
                httpTransport,
                jsonFactory,
                new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                        .setTransport(httpTransport)
                        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                        .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                        .build()
                        .setRefreshToken(refreshToken)
        ).build();
    }
```

The problem in above is that GoogleCredential is deprecated. What is they non-deprecated way to do this?

We are using following lib:

```
com.google.apis.google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev20190807-1.30.10
```

Answer (score 1):

- `Google Credential` is not fully deprecated, it depends on the library you are using (`com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.17.1` should still work)
- An any case, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/commit/45825c4157eee2a7254817b1aae9aa63ba726726) the non-deprecated way is to use [Google Auth Library for Java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java)
- There are samples for different ways to build the credentials - depending on your use case.